# Override Dockerfile CMD by docker run command with arguments

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile with CMD.
I want to override this command by docker run command
but in my command there are arguments.
the command is something like that:
MyAppName -DataBase myDataBase -Port myPort -AnotherARG arg
The arguments are difference in any container launch that means that I must not feed all argument at every container launch (there are a lot of arguments)
how can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

So what is the problem?

If command line is completely different on every launch, you'd better not declare `CMD` nor `ENTRYPOINT` at your `Dockerfile`, but provide it each time on launch:

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/sh -c "echo Hello World"
```

If there is common part, lets say you always need a shell, but arguments differ, then you declare `ENTRYPOINT` in your `Dockerfile` like:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
....
ENTRYPOINT ['/bin/sh']
```

And provide the remaining arguments on launch:

```
docker run -it mycontainer -c 'Hello World!
```

You need to remember:

- Arguments, provided in `docker run` are concatenated to `Dockerfile`'s `ENTRYPOINT`
- Arguments, provided in `docker run` override `Dockerfile`'s `CMD`
- You should use `ENTRYPOINT ['blah', 'blah']` syntax instead of `ENTRYPOINT blah blah` in `Dockerfile` for this to work

Answer (score 0):

As @grapes says in their answer,

> Arguments, provided in `docker run` are concatenated to `Dockerfile`'s `ENTRYPOINT`

So you can write a custom `ENTRYPOINT` script that looks at the command that's getting passed in and rewrite it if you need to.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#
# docker-entrypoint.sh
#
# The Dockerfile CMD, or any "docker run" command option, gets
# passed as command-line arguments to this script.

# Abort on any error (good shell hygiene)
set -e

# If we're running "myAppName", provide default options
if [ "$1" = "MyAppName" ]; then
  # Remove the command from the option list (we know it)
  shift

  # Then run it with default options plus whatever else
  # was given in the command
  exec MyAppName -OptionOne default -OtherOption foo "$@"
fi

# Otherwise just run what was given in the command
exec "$@"
```

The conditional block there ensures that, for instance, if you want a debugging shell with `docker run --rm -it ... sh` it doesn't get your application-specific options added in.  You can get arbitrarily complex here, setting default environment variables, trying to further parse the command line, and so on.  It's important to `exec` the main process in the entrypoint script so that the application becomes the main container process and it doesn't keep the entrypoint as a parent (you want `docker stop` to send its signals to your process and not a wrapper shell).

Again quoting @grapes:

> You should use `ENTRYPOINT ['blah', 'blah']` syntax instead of `ENTRYPOINT blah blah` in `Dockerfile` for this to work

So your `Dockerfile` might end like:

```sh
...
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["MyAppName"]
```

(The `chmod` step is unnecessary if the file is already executable on your local system before it gets `COPY`d in.  The square brackets and quotes on both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are critical.)